# Select Multiple Images using Android Intents

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to select multiple **Images** using **Android Intents**.

Is it possible ?

How I can achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a standard `Intent` for retrieving several images in one request.